# Por que o POST não está funcionando no meu MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js

Sempre que executo o comando post o insomnia me retorna um User vazio.

```
router.post('/register', async (req,res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    try {
        if (await User.findOne({ email }))
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Usuário Existente'});

        const user = await User.create(req.body);
        user.senha = undefined;

        return res.send({
            user,
            token: geradortoken({ id:user.id }), 
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({error: 'Falha no registro'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para retornar as informações passadas para a criação do usuário, tente colocar no lugar de:

```
return res.send();
```

Colocar:

```
return res.json(user);
```

Assim será retornado um JSON com as informações do user através do Insomnia.

Espero ter ajudado.